# Alerta o usuário que ele não escolheu um type=radio;

Tags: javascript, dom, value

Estou com um problema de não saber como identificar se o usuário selecionou uma opção `type=radio`.

Segue o código:

```js
let nComputador = "";
let nJogador = "";
//let minhaEscolha = document.querySelector("input[type='radio']:checked").value;

function sortear(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
};

let play = document.getElementById("jogar").addEventListener('click', function() {

  let minhaEscolha = document.querySelector("input[type='radio']:checked").value;

  if (minhaEscolha === null) {
    return alert("escolha uma opção!")
  }

  nJogador = parseFloat(document.querySelector("#meuNumero").value);

  nComputador = sortear(10);

  if (isNaN(nJogador)) {
    return alert("digite um numero");
  }

  let soma = ((nJogador + nComputador) % 2 === 0) ? "par" : "impar";
  let resultado = (soma == minhaEscolha) ? alert("ganhei") : alert("computador ganhou");

  console.log(nComputador, nJogador, minhaEscolha, soma);
});
```

```html
<body>

  <h1>
    jogo do par ou impar
  </h1>
  <p>
    Digite um número de 0 a 10:
    <input type="number" id="meuNumero" min="0" max="10">
    <label><input type="radio" name="escolha" value="par">Par</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="escolha" value="impar">Impar</label>
  </p>
  <button id="jogar">Jogar</button>
</body>
```

Esse `if` não deveria funcionar?

```
if (minhaEscolha === null) {
    return alert("escolha uma opção!")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema está antes do `if (minhaEscolha === null)`, neste trecho:

```
document.querySelector("input[type='radio']:checked").value
```

Você está procurando por um `radio` que esteja marcado (`checked`). Mas se nenhum estiver marcado, o `querySelector` não encontra nada e [retorna `null`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector#Return_value). E ao tentar pegar o `value` de `null`, dá erro.

Uma solução é primeiro verificar se o `querySelector` retornou alguma coisa, e só depois pegar o `value`:

```js
let nComputador = "";
let nJogador = "";

function sortear(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
};

let play = document.getElementById("jogar").addEventListener('click', function() {

  // verificar se algum radio foi marcado (não pega o value ainda)
  let minhaEscolha = document.querySelector("input[type='radio']:checked");

  if (!minhaEscolha) { // se nenhum radio foi marcado
    return alert("escolha uma opção!");
  }

  // pegar o valor do radio marcado
  minhaEscolha = minhaEscolha.value;

  nJogador = parseFloat(document.querySelector("#meuNumero").value);

  nComputador = sortear(10);

  if (isNaN(nJogador)) {
    return alert("digite um numero");
  }

  let soma = ((nJogador + nComputador) % 2 === 0) ? "par" : "impar";
  let resultado = (soma == minhaEscolha) ? alert("ganhei") : alert("computador ganhou");

  console.log(nComputador, nJogador, minhaEscolha, soma);
});
```

```html
<body>

  <h1>
    jogo do par ou impar
  </h1>
  <p>
    Digite um número de 0 a 10:
    <input type="number" id="meuNumero" min="0" max="10">
    <label><input type="radio" name="escolha" value="par">Par</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="escolha" value="impar">Impar</label>
  </p>
  <button id="jogar">Jogar</button>
</body>
```

Você também pode optar por usar [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) em vez de [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat), já que um jogo de par ou ímpar - pelo que sei - só usa números inteiros.

Comment: Entendi, eu verifiquei o código que tinha feito parecido, porém logo depois do if(!minhaEscolha) eu tinha colocado um else para pegar o value, isto interfere?

Comment: @PatrickEidrian Como dentro do `if (!minhaEscolha)` tem um `return`, se entrar no `if` ele sai da função, então o `else` neste caso não faz diferença. veja aqui: https://ideone.com/84lyHS

Comment: Não sabia dessa parte do `return`, e sobre o `parseFloat` eu geralmente coloco por causa do usuário sabe, não sei o que ele pode tentar. **obrigado**

Comment: @PatrickEidrian `parseInt("2.5")` vai arredondar para `2`, então vc decide o que é melhor no seu caso, aceitar `2.5` (que nunca será par, pois o resto da divisão é `0.5`), ou arredondar automaticamente com `parseInt`.

Comment: é realmente melhor o `parseInt`, outra dica valiosa (y)